# Facing Issues While Uploading App on Google play Made via Buildozer

Tags: android, upload, kivy, buildozer

I have made an app using command `buildozer android debug deploy run`

and then i goto my new account of gmail and simply went to devloper console and tried to upload this new apk but it says me

> Upload failed
>
> You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs.
>
> You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode. Learn more about signing.

I have also uploaded images just check it out[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `release` command instead of `debug` for publishing in Play Store.

You need to sign the apk manually after that:

> Buildozer can't currently do this part for you. You need to follow the instructions at https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html - specifically, step 1 with keytool, step 3 with jarsigner and step 4 with zipalign. You don't need step 2, that's what buildozer takes care of.
>
> This isn't too hard, just 3 terminal commands, and one of them (generating your key store) only needs to be done once.
>
> You should also read about safely securing your keys. If you lose them you won't be able to sign apps any more - you can create a new one, but then can't upgrade existing apps easily and need to make a new Play store entry etc.

[Quote source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kivy-users/5-G7wkbHb_k/KUZ4U0ZMIdgJ).

Right link for instructions: https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually

Comment: My friend i tried it and it gave me an unsigned apk which also gave me error on google play

Comment: I am not that geek...so is there any method that is easy like one click

Comment: @Nisarg I think there isn't, but I can be wrong. I don't know about them and couldn't find any.